# How to retrieve key & values from hashmap

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to insert the values to hash map through object, and i want to check if the values are inserted in to hash map. so i am using this code but in runtime i am not able to get any output.

How to resolve this?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class TaskList
{   

    private static HashMap<Integer, Object[]> dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    private static  HashMap<Integer, Object[]> screen_dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    public final static Object[][] longValues = {{"10", "kstc-proc", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},{"11", "proc-lvk1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},{"13", "trng-lvk1", "4.6.1.","3","O"}};
    private static String sl,pid,tid,mval,status;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        addTask();
    }

    public static void addTask()
    {  
        for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
        {
        screen_dataz.put(k,longValues);
        }
        Set mapSet = (Set) screen_dataz.entrySet();
        Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();
        while (mapIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
        String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
        String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the loop you should do `screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);` Look at your `HashMap` again and you'll understand why.

Comment: Please use generics to avoid potential errors due to wrong typecasting.

Comment: 99% of the time using Object is wrong. All the times you've used Object[] they seem to actually be String[] in this case

Comment: As proposed on your earlier questions: Java is an OOP language. You'll produce easier to write and maintain code if you start using custom classes. `Object`, `Object[]` and `Object[][]` are very bad design decisions (in most cases - most certainly in yours).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must add a row of the `longValues` matrix to the map, and not the whole matrix:

```
 for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
 {
     screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
 }
```

Then, while iterating extract the value as `Object[]` and not `String`, and key as `Integer`

```
 while (mapIterator.hasNext()) 
 {
     Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
     Integer keyValue = (Integer) mapEntry.getKey();
     Object[] value = (Object[]) mapEntry.getValue();
     //iterate over the array and print each value
     for (int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code with a few fixes/improvements:

- **do not use casting when using generics**
- the loop adding elements to `screen_dataz` was always adding the same object
- the value stored in the map is an array which means it will not be printed as you expect with a simple call to `toString()`

  ```
  public class TaskList {
      private static HashMap<Integer, String[]> dataz = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
      private static HashMap<Integer, String[]> screen_dataz = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
      public final static String[][] longValues = {
              { "10", "kstc-proc", "10.10.10.10.10.", "5", "O" },
              { "11", "proc-lvk1", "12.1.2.", "4", "O" },
              { "13", "trng-lvk1", "4.6.1.", "3", "O" } };
      private static String sl, pid, tid, mval, status;

      public static void main(String args[]) {
          addTask();
      }

      public static void addTask() {
          for (int k = 0; k < longValues.length; k++) {
              screen_dataz.put(k, longValues[k]);
          }
          Set<Entry<Integer, String[]>> mapSet = screen_dataz.entrySet();
          Iterator<Entry<Integer, String[]>> mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();
          while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
              Entry<Integer, String[]> mapEntry = mapIterator.next();
              Integer keyValue = mapEntry.getKey();
              String[] value = mapEntry.getValue();
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: +1 - that fixes the majority of the issues. You can still change `Object` to `String`, though.

Comment: @Andreas I did, but reverted this change, thought that maybe there was some reason why the OP has chosen `Object` over `String`, if not then just replace `Object` with `String`.

Answer (score 1):

One correction in your code:

You may want to update your for loop

as

```
 for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
    {
    screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `for` loop to populate to `screen_dataz` like this.

```
for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
{
    screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
}
```

Next, make the below change:-

```
String keyValue = mapEntry.getKey().toString();
String value = Arrays.asList((Object[])mapEntry.getValue()).toString();
```

This will print your value properly.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things to comment about this code.

First, the generic arguments of the parameterized type are incorrect.  The map is currently storing `Map<Long,Object[]>` however objects of type `Object[][]` are added to the `Map`.  I assume you want to enter each `Object[]` as a separate `Entry` in the `Map`.

```
    for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
    {
    screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
    }
```

The second piece to look at is the iteration over the `Map` entries.  Instead of using the `Iterator` use a `for..each` loop.

```
    for(Entry<Integer,Object[]> entry: screen_dataz.entrySet()){
       //repetitive task
    }
```

**Final Output**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class TaskList
{   

    private static HashMap<Integer, Object[]> dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    private static  HashMap<Integer, Object[]> screen_dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    public final static Object[][] longValues = {{"10", "kstc-proc", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},{"11", "proc-lvk1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},{"13", "trng-lvk1", "4.6.1.","3","O"}};
    private static String sl,pid,tid,mval,status;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        addTask();
    }

    public static void addTask()
    {  
        for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
        {
        screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
        }

        for(Entry<Integer,Object[]> entry: screen_dataz.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for(Object obj: entry.getValue()){
                    System.out.println(obj.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);` in a loop will help you.
You could also use an Iterator for this.