# How to print each hashmap values separately

Tags: java

i am trying to retrieve and display the Hash map values in this code,but i want the output to be separate values...how can i do this

code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class TaskList
{   

    private static HashMap<Integer, Object[]> dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    private static  HashMap<Integer, Object[]> screen_dataz = new HashMap<Integer,Object[]>();
    public final static Object[][] longValues = {{"10", "kstc-proc", "10.10.","5","O"},{"11", "proc-lvk1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},{"13", "trng-lvk1", "4.6.1.","3","O"}};
    private static String sl,pid,tid,mval,status;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        addTask();
    }

    public static void addTask()
    {  
        for (int k=0; k<longValues.length; k++)
        {
        screen_dataz.put(k,longValues[k]);
        }
        Set mapSet = (Set) screen_dataz.entrySet();
        Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();
        while (mapIterator.hasNext()) 
 {
     Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
     Integer keyValue = (Integer) mapEntry.getKey();
     Object[] value = (Object[]) mapEntry.getValue();
     //iterate over the array and print each value
     for (int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
    }
}
```

now i am getting output like this:

output:

```
10 kstc-proc 10.10. 5 O 
11 proc-lvk1 12.1.2. 4 O 
13 trng-lvk1 4.6.1. 3 O
```

i want output like this for one set. say for 3rd line of output

output:

```
13
trng-lvk1
4.6.1.
3
O
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve key & values from hashmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338480/how-to-retrieve-key-values-from-hashmap)

Comment: I guess coding is really painful experience for you.

Comment: @AdamSiemion: I don't think so. `Step 1:` Copy code to SO. `Step 2:` Paste answer. `Step 3:` goto step 1

Comment: @jlordo Right.. I forgot to add **in your IDE not on SO** :)

Comment: Hope i got another experience in coding

Comment: @BaliMozillasMoMo: This a good place to start: [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) All of us started at this or a similar point once (except Ryan Gosling :P).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously, that is your question? I propbably shouldn't answer this.

replace

```
System.out.print(value[i] + " ");
```

with

```
System.out.println(value[i] + " ");
                ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your for loop like this:

```
   for (int i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
         String arr[] = (String[])values[i];
         for(int k = 0 ; k < arr.length; k++) {
            System.out.println(arr[k]);
         }

     }
```

Comment: use println instead. OP needs each entry on a new line.